# must declare scalar variable error "@f_ndoganor"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I get the error `must declare scalar variable error "@f_ndoganor"` at `@f_ndoganor`... I changed type of `@f_ndoganor` many types, as numeric, as int, as varchar... but I can't solve the problem ...

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO table_regjistrimi (f_kodi, f_emertimi,f_emri,f_shteti,f_lloj_kodi,f_vendodhja,f_vitiushtrimor,f_telefoni,f_email,f_web,f_nbiznesit,f_dbiznesit,f_nfiskal,f_dfiskal,f_ntvsh,f_dtvsh,f_ndoganore,f_ddoganore,f_npunes,f_dpunes,f_nlicenca,f_dlicenca,f_drejtori,f_rf,f_kontabilisti,f_konsumatori,f_autorizuari,f_npunesuarve,f_shenime) values (@f_kodi, @f_emertimi, @f_emri, @f_shteti, @f_lloj_kodi, @f_vendodhja, @f_vitiushtrimor, @f_telefoni, @f_email, @f_web, @f_nbiznesit, @f_dbiznesit, @f_nfiskal, @f_dfiskal, @f_ntvsh, @f_dtvsh, @f_ndoganore, @f_ddoganore, @f_npunes, @f_dpunes, @f_nlicenca, @f_dlicenca, @f_drejtori, @f_rf, @f_kontabilisti, @f_konsumatori, @f_autorizuari, @f_npunesuarve, @f_shenime)";


conn.Open();
try
{
    SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns,conn);

    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_kodi", textBox1.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_emertimi", textBox2.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_emri", textBox3.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_shteti", textBox4.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_lloj_kodi", comboBox1.SelectedText);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_vendodhja", textBox5.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresa", textBox6.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_vitiushtrimor", textBox7.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_telefoni", textBox8.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_email", textBox9.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_web", textBox10.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_nbiznesit", textBox15.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_dbiznesit", textBox21.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_nfiskal", textBox16.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_dfiskal", textBox22.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_ntvsh", textBox17.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_dtvsh", textBox23.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_ndoganor", textBox18.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_ddoganor", textBox24.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_npunes", textBox19.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_dpunes", textBox25.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_nlicenca", textBox20.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_dlicenca", textBox26.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_drejtori", textBox30.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_rf", textBox31.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_kontabilisti", textBox32.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_konsumatori", textBox33.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_autorizuari", textBox34.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_npunesuarve", textBox35.Text);
    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_shenime", textBox36.Text);
    cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //admin
}
    catch (Exception ex )
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: The error says to declare the variable; changing the data types isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

You get a `must declare scalar variable` error whenever you have a variable (preceded with a `@`) that is not declared either explicitly through a `DECLARE` statement or implicitly through a parameter value.

In your case, you've got a misspelling between your query and your parameters:

Query:

```
 @f_ndoganore, @f_ddoganore,
```

Paremeters:

```
 cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_ndoganor", textBox18.Text);
 cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_ddoganor", textBox24.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its spelled @f_ndoganore in the INSERT statement and @f_ndoganor in the parameters.Add() list.

Correct the spelling and it should be able to map the parameter correctly.